# Von Neumann stability analysis in 3d

Tags: pde, numerical-analysis, stability, cfl

I need to get a stability criterion for the numerical scheme for equation

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}-\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial y^2}-\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2} -\alpha\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-\beta\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}-\gamma\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}-f=0 $$

The scheme is explicit:
$$ \frac{u^{n+1}_{i,j,k}-u^{n}_{i,j,k}}{\Delta t}=\frac{u^{n}_{i+1,j,k}-2u^{n}_{i,j,k}+u^{n}_{i-1,j,k}}{\Delta x^2}+\frac{u^{n}_{i,j+1,k}-2u^{n}_{i,j,k}+u^{n}_{i,j-1,k}}{\Delta y^2}+$$
$$+\frac{u^{n}_{i,j,k+1}-2u^{n}_{i,j,k}+u^{n}_{i,j,k-1}}{\Delta z^2}+\alpha\frac{u^{n}_{i+1,j,k}-u^{n}_{i-1,j,k}}{2\Delta x }+$$
$$+\beta\frac{u^{n}_{i,j+1,k}-u^{n}_{i,j-1,k}}{2\Delta y }+\gamma\frac{u^{n}_{i,j,k+1}-u^{n}_{i,j,k-1}}{2\Delta z }+f_{i,j,k}.$$
After that I found an expression with a help of von Neumann analysis for amplification coefficient:

$$\rho=1-4\Delta t\left(\frac{\sin^2{\theta /2}}{\Delta x^2}+\frac{\sin^2{\eta /2}}{\Delta y^2}+\frac{\sin^2{\zeta /2}}{\Delta z^2}\right)+i\Delta t\left(\alpha\frac{\sin{\theta}}{\Delta x}+\beta\frac{\sin{\eta}}{\Delta y}+\gamma\frac{\sin{\zeta }}{\Delta z}\right) $$

To find a condition for stability criterion I must find a condition for $\Delta t,\Delta x,\Delta y,\Delta z$ so that for all $\theta,\eta,\zeta$ an inequality $|\rho|<1$ is true. Here I stuck.Could you help me with this stuff?

Comment: What expression do you obtain when you substitute an arbitrary fourier mode?

Comment: @Paul (who asked the question) you should put your comment into the body of the question.  Then look for conditions under which $|\rho|\le 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though your problem is in 3 dimensions, you can gain a lot of insight by considering the 1D case.  Let's omit the y and z terms and concentrate on x and t.  Then, your problem would be equivalent to the classic advection-diffusion equation with an explicit Forward-in-Time, Centered-in-Space (FTCS) finite difference method.

Knowing the name of the problem and the method, it's fairly easy to find derivations online.  I personally found [this stability analysis for the advection diffusion equation](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jhm/ME540/lectures/ConvDiff/ConvDiff.pdf) particularly insightful.  Following this approach, you should be able to extrapolate a method for the 3D case.